# Link to relative files in Asciidoc

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

I'm writing a document using asciidoc and asciidoctor. So, I'm having a intro.adoc file and then bunch of section files. So, what I want to do is list them on to intro.adoc and add hyperlinks to them so that it will be easy to navigate.

For this I can think of two approaches:

First, I can use headers and associate a relative link to .adoc files in the same directory. So, that they will redirect to them. But I don't know how to achieve it. `link: == section1.adoc[Section 1]` is not working.

Second, using `include::section1.adoc[]`. Its working but its not a hyperlink.

What is wrong with it? or is there a easy way to do it.

#### Edit

If its not clear, I'm trying to achieve this `# [Section1](section.md)`(Markdown version) in asciidoc.

Comment: @ AnkitRGadiya: have you found a solution in the meantime?

Answer (score 5):

What about:

```
<<section1.adoc#Section1,your link>>
```

See:
https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/macros/inter-document-xref/

Comment: Yes the hyperlink is working but it is similar to this `link:section1.adoc[Section 1]` and what I want is that it renders as a hyperlink in Header. 
Thanks anyways

Comment: (since the nickname tag doesn't work under the OP, I repeat my question under an answer.)

@AnkitRGadiya: have you found a solution in the meantime?